# why is output like this why does second row gives NULL value in second column select stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',date '2015-02-02',2)

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform, hdp

why is output like this why does second row gives `NULL` value in second column `select stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',date '2015-02-02',2)`:

```sql
0: jdbc:hive2://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:1> select  stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',date '2015-02-02',2) as (col0,col1,col2,col3);
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: UDFArgumentException Argument 2's type (int) should be equal to argument 6's type (date) (state=42000,code=40000)

0: jdbc:hive2://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:1> select  stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',20,date '2015-02-02') as (col0,col1,col2,col3);

INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20191225124022_380b3a4c-9870-4f5c-89c8-a696af39f985): select  stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',20,date '2015-02-02') as (col0,col1,col2,col3)


INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)

INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:col0, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:col1, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:col2, type:date, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:col3, type:int, comment:null)], properties:null)

INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20191225124022_380b3a4c-9870-4f5c-89c8-a696af39f985); Time taken: 0.545 seconds


INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20191225124022_380b3a4c-9870-4f5c-89c8-a696af39f985): select  stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',20,date '2015-02-02') as (col0,col1,col2,col3)


INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20191225124022_380b3a4c-9870-4f5c-89c8-a696af39f985); Time taken: 0.006 seconds

INFO  : OK



| col0  | col1  |    col2     | col3  |

| A     | 10    | 2015-01-01  | 1     |

| B     | NULL  | 2015-02-02  | 1     |

2 rows selected (0.594 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hive 1.2 your select statement throws exception:

```
select stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',date '2015-02-02',2);
```

> FAILED: UDFArgumentException Argument 2's type (int) should be equal to argument 6's type (date)

first argument of stack (2) says that there are two tuples. **These tuples should have the same schema.**
First tuple:

```
'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1 --this one contains 4 columns
```

Second tuple:

```
'B',date '2015-02-02',2 --this one contains 3 columns
```

Add some int second column after 'B' to match the first tuple. It can be null, but it should be in the second tuple. I added 20:

```
select stack(2,'A',10,date '2015-01-01',1,'B',20, date '2015-02-02',2);

OK
A       10      2015-01-01      1
B       20      2015-02-02      2
Time taken: 0.363 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: But why was there a null value In my run

Comment: @AbhishekNimje Your Hive version works differently... And not only that null. I noticed in your result dataset col3 in the second row, it should be 2, but it is 1, weird also

Comment: Means it does not always give same result  on different versions

Comment: @AbhishekNimje anyway, fixed sentence will work the same on your Hive